# Laravel "Three-Way" Pivot Table?

Tags: laravel, pivot, relation

OP:

I have a page called "Groceries" on my site. For this, I am using two tables:

```
Categories [$this->hasMany('App\Product')]
- id
- name

Products [$this->belongsTo('App\Category')]
- id
- category_id
- name
```

Simple Stuff. In my query I collect all categories with their corresponding products. `groceries = Category::with('products')->get();`

Then in my view I can access all categories with their products and list them nicely, all categories will be displayed once, and below the category name will be my products. All good. Example:

```
Category Alcohol
- Beer
- Wine
- Whisky

Category Bread
- Brown Bread
- White Bread
```

.. and so on.

And then it's where it gets tricky, at least for me. Up untill now I've been using the above method for one simple grocery list. But now I want to add another table, called "Groceries", in which I store grocery lists. Like so:

```
Groceries
- id
- name
```

With this, I think a pivot table would come in handy, but I am unsure about what to store in the pivot table and how to access all the data:

```
category_product?
grocery_product?
- id
- grocery_id
- product_id?
- category_id? I don't think I need to store this in the pivot table, it can be accessed through the Products model?
- number
```

I've been having a hard time to comprehend a "simple" pivot table, and now it gets even more tricky, with a "three-way" pivot table.

I wish to store the following in my pivot table:

The grocery id of the grocery list. But then I get stuck. What else should I store in the pivot table, in order for me to be able to still keep using the above method, but then with an extra parameter, like so:

```
$groceries = Grocery::find($id)->with('categories')->with('products'); ?
```

What I personally am thinking, is that I `should` use the following relation in my Groceries model?:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category')->with('App\Product');
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction to help point my mind in the right direction would already help tons.

Edit:

Model User:

```
public function groceries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Grocery');
}
```

Model Category:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Model Products:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Model Groceries:

```
// No relations yet
```

Edit #2:
On my groceries.index page I have a simple list of grocery lists for the current logged in user. They can create, edit or delete grocery lists.

Once the user clicks on "Create Grocery List", I show a view with all categories and their corresponding products, like so:

```
Category Alcohol
- [ ] Beer
- [ ] Wine
- [ ] Whisky

Category Bread
- [ ] Brown Bread
- [ ] White Bread
```

The [ ] stands for a checkbox. The user can select which products he or she wants to add to the list. Upon saving, I want to store the grocery list ID in a pivot table with the product ID's that were selected.

Then, on the edit form, I want to show the same view, but with the saved products already selected. So, I think the best way to accomplish this is to store the grocery ID in the pivot table, and it's selected products. Then, on the edit form, I simply check if the product ID exists, and if it does, the checkbox should be checked. But I am stuck with how the relations should be like and what I actually should be storing in my pivot table, product id's as I said or shouldn't I even use a pivot table at all?

Comment: What is a Grocery list in your case? `User ID 1 has: One wine, two beers, one cheese` - something like that or no?

Comment: explain the relation of Grocery with categories and/or products.

Comment: Please provide relationships between category,groceries and product..

Comment: Apologies, added them in above

Comment: @Kaloyan Doichinov. One user can have multiple grocery lists. A grocery list consists simply of a list of products. But I think I indeed need to elaborate on this in the OP. Will do :)

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov, I've edited my question again to explain this a bit more.

Comment: @RonBrouwers thanks, I'll try to come up with a schema example in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it:

1. A Product `belongsTo` a Category, in your case.
2. Consequently, a Category `hasMany` Products.
3. User `hasMany` "grocery lists", each one of which `hasMany` Products
4. So a List also `belongsTo` one specific User
5. Therefore, a Product will also `belongsToMany` Lists

This spares you the trouble of having to do a 3-way pivot, and Eloquent will let you conveniently walk through any and all relationships of any model that you might need when populating the check-box list in your description.
Here's a [simple schema](http://www.laravelsd.com/share/Gb9TRt) to serve as an example - might need some tweaking!

I would, however, prefer Query Builder or plain raw DB queries instead of Eloquent methods for complex JOINs like these, as the Relationship Builder in Laravel actually does a `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)`, which is a bit worse in terms of performance compared to a regular join. See these for reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Comment: Thanks, although number 3 and 5 were things I wasn't sure of. But now that you put it like this, it makes perfect sense actually. Now time to try and wrap my head around it :D